# MVP in Android app - Presenter state

Tags: java, android, mvp, android-savedstate, presenter

I work with map in Android. So, I want to save state of some of my presenters to save data, when I leaved activity(not when rotate the screen). I can't find the solution besides singleton with ArrayList, but I would like to use already written solution. Thanks.

Comment: Checkout Mosby, Moxy, Nucleus & ThirtyInch & also feel free to go through all available ones in [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/163). Personally, I had used Mosby to create ViewState and save viewstate information.

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Android Boilerplate](https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate) source code which uses Dependency Injection and persists presenters via [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/) Scopes.